# How to get the last element of a json file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
 $.getJSON('./file-read?filename='+filename+'&parameter='+parameter, function(data) {
var firstElement = data[0][0];
var lastElement =  ?
});
```

I try to find out the last Element in my JSON file.

My JSON File looks like this:

```
[[1392418800000,6.9],[1392419400000,7],[1392420000000,7.1],[1392420600000,7.2],[1392421200000,7.2]]
```

can anybody help me to read extract the last date(1392421200000) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pick the `(length - 1)`<sup>th</sup> element with this:

```
var lastElement = data[data.length-1][0];
```

Another way is to use array methods, e.g. `pop` which will return the last element of the array:

```
var lastElement = data.pop()[0];
```

**N.B.:** The first approach is *the fastest way* of picking the last element, however the second approach will implicitly remove the last element from `data` array. So if you plan to use the initial array later in your code, be sure to use either the first method or alternative solution provided by [@matewka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22476872/1249581).

Answer (score 3):

VisioN's answer is nice and easy. Here's another approach:

```
var lastElement = data.slice(-1)[0];
// output: [1392421200000,7.2]
```

Negative number in the `slice` method makes the slice count from the end of the array. I find this method more compact and simpler but the disadvantage is that it returns a smaller, 1-element array instead of the element you wanted to fetch. If you want to fetch only the timestamp you'd have to add another `[0]` to the end of the expression, like this:

```
var lastElement = data.slice(-1)[0][0];
// output: 1392421200000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
var data = " any json data";
var lastelement = data[ Object.keys(obj).sort().pop() ];
```

`Object.keys` (ES5, shimmable) returns an array of the object's keys. We then sort them and grab the last one.

Comment: that works - but with one fix:
var lastelement = data[ Object.keys(data).sort().pop() ];